# How to calculate the height of a textarea in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamically loaded form via a directive.

The form includes several tabs and several accordion.

In the agreements there are Textarea already having contents loaded with the form.

I would like the height of the Textarea to be automatically calculated according to their adequate content.

I recovered a solution that allows me to calculate the correct height of the textarea unfortunately it does it only on the first tab.

If I change tab the height remains at 0 while there is a lot of content.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

I was thinking of using a $watch() at tab change to restart the function rezise.

Here is the html code of the form :

```
<form name="formData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate data-html-validation>
<tabset class="tabset">
    <tab ng-repeat="data in ctrl.dataMap" heading="{{data.label}}" disabled="{{!data.sections.length}}" select="ctrl.alertMe($event)">
        <tab-heading>
            <div class="wrapper">
                {{data.label}}
               <span class="text" ng-if="data.notification!=undefined"> {{data.notification}}</span>
            </div>
        </tab-heading>
        <accordion close-others="false" class="ctnAccordion">
            <accordion-group heading="{{group.label}}" is-open="true" ng-repeat="group in data.sections">
                <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="line in group.fields" >
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4">{{line.name}}</label>
                        <div ng-switch="line.type">
                            <div class="col-lg-8" ng-switch-when='ALPHANUM'>
                                <textarea elastic class="form-control" maxlength="255" ng-model="line.value" rows="1" cols="20" wrap="hard"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Here is the code of the directive used :

```
directives.directive('elastic', [
'$timeout',
function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.initialHeight = $scope.initialHeight || element[0].style.height;
            var resize = function() {
                element[0].style.height = $scope.initialHeight;
                element[0].style.height = "" + element[0].scrollHeight + "px";
            };

            element.on("blur keyup change", resize);
            $timeout(resize, 0);
            $scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, resize);
        }
    };
 }
]);
```

Comment: The tabs probably work by applying `display:none` to the inactive tabs. You can not determine the dimensions of any element that has this style, or any of its descendants. You would need to do that _after_ the individual tab has been made visible for the first time.

Comment: @misorude, I also think that the problem is that the tab is not active, in fact it should detect the tab change in the directive